# nullpointerexception when reloading listview after update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a listview which when clicked opens a dialog box where list items are edited and on submitting changes goes back to the listview. My problem is I get a nullpointerexception when it tries to reload the listview.

The function getCurrentSalesRecords() is used to populate the listview the first time the activity is called and after updating:

```
    public ArrayList<SalesReciepts> getCurrentSalesRecords() {

    ArrayList<SalesReciepts> sale = new ArrayList<SalesReciepts>();

    Double invoice_id = Double.parseDouble(GlobalApp.data().id);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "";
        sql += "SELECT entry_id, product_description, quantity, total FROM " + SalesReceiptsConstants.NewConstants.ENTRY_TABLE_NAME;
        sql += " WHERE " + SalesReceiptsConstants.NewConstants.INVOICE_NO + " = " + invoice_id;



        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);


    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        SalesReciepts sales = new SalesReciepts();
        sales.setEntryId(cursor.getInt(0));
        sales.setProduct(cursor.getString(1));
        sales.setQty(cursor.getInt(2));
        sales.setTotal(cursor.getDouble(3));

        sale.add(sales);
    }
    return sale;
}
```

onFinishDialog() method in tab host:

```
    public void onFinishDialog() {
    if (confirm != null) {

        confirm.updateView();

        //mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

List View Fragment:

```
public class confirmFragmentTab extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    OnItemLongClickListener {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "sales_list";

//Context context;
ListView saleListView;
ArrayList<SalesReciepts> salesReciept;
SalesListAdapter salesListAdapter;
ProductsDbHelper db;
Activity activity;


private GetEmpTask task;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    db = new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity());
    //saleListView = new ListView(getActivity());
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_layout, container, false);
    findViewsById(rootView);
    task = new GetEmpTask(getActivity());
    task.execute((Void) null);

    saleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    saleListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}

private void findViewsById(View view) {
    saleListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sale);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {


    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
    SalesReciepts sale = (SalesReciepts) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

    if (sale != null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putParcelable("selectedSale", sale);
        CustomEditDialog customDialogFragment = new CustomEditDialog();
        customDialogFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        customDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),
                CustomEditDialog.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long arg3) {
    SalesReciepts sale = (SalesReciepts) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    // Use AsyncTask to delete from database
    db.delete(sale);
    salesListAdapter.remove(sale);
    return true;
}

public class GetEmpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<SalesReciepts>> {

    private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    public GetEmpTask(Activity context)
    {
        this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<SalesReciepts> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> saleList =    db.getCurrentSalesRecords();
        return saleList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SalesReciepts> sList) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null
                && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            Log.d("sales", sList.toString());
            salesReciept = sList;
            if (sList != null) {
                if (sList.size() != 0) {
                    salesListAdapter = new SalesListAdapter(activity,
                            sList);
                    saleListView.setAdapter(salesListAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Sales Records",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

/*
 * This method is invoked from Invoice3 onFinishDialog() method. It is
 * called from CustomEditDialog when a sale record is updated.
 * This is used for communicating between fragments.
 */
public void updateView() {
    task = new GetEmpTask(activity);
    task.execute((Void) null);

}


}
```

Dialog box fragment:

```
public class CustomEditDialog extends DialogFragment {

// UI references
private EditText saleProduct;
private EditText saleQty;
private EditText saleTotal;
private LinearLayout submitLayout;

private SalesReciepts sales;

private static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

ProductsDbHelper db;

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "sale_dialog_fragment";

public interface saleDialogFragmentListener {
    void onFinishDialog();
}

public CustomEditDialog() {



}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    db = new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity());

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    sales = bundle.getParcelable("selectedSale");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View customDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_sale,
            null);
    builder.setView(customDialogView);

    saleProduct = (EditText) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.editProduct);
    saleQty = (EditText) customDialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.editQty);
    saleTotal = (EditText) customDialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTotal);
    submitLayout = (LinearLayout) customDialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.layout_submit);
    submitLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    setValue();

    builder.setTitle(R.string.update_sale);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.update,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    sales.setProduct(saleProduct.getText().toString());
                    sales.setQty(Integer.parseInt(saleQty.getText().toString()));
                    sales.setTotal(Double.parseDouble(saleTotal.getText().toString()));

                    long result = db.update(sales);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        Invoice3 invoice = (Invoice3)getActivity();
                        invoice.onFinishDialog();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Unable to update record",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    return alertDialog;
}

private void setValue() {
    if (sales != null) {
        saleProduct.setText(sales.getProduct());
        saleQty.setText(sales.getQty() + "");
        saleTotal.setText(String.valueOf(sales.getTotal()));

    }
}
}
```

LOGS:

```
08-11 09:06:56.796    1700-1725/com.example.Prototype E/AndroidRuntime﹕     
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.example.Prototype, PID: 1700
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.Prototype.confirmFragmentTab$GetEmpTask.doInBackground(confirmFragmentTab.java:115)
        at com.example.Prototype.confirmFragmentTab$GetEmpTask.doInBackground(confirmFragmentTab.java:104)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Null pointer at:

```
  protected ArrayList<SalesReciepts> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> saleList =    db.getCurrentSalesRecords();
        return saleList;

    }
```

**UPDATE**

Placed

```
db = new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity());
```

in doInBackground(). Still getting a null pointer error but cannot identify source.

LOG:

```
 08-11 09:45:18.347    1253-1495/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1711 uid 10052
08-11 09:45:18.417    1416-1445/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
 08-11 09:45:19.747    1253-1267/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.Prototype/.Check: +2s441ms
```

**UPDATE**

changed 
    db = new ProductsDbHelper(thisActivity());
to
    db = new ProductsDbHelper(activity);

Null pointer exception at:

```
db = getReadableDatabase();
```

LOG:

```
08-11 10:15:55.901    1739-1784/com.example.Prototype E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.Prototype, PID: 1739
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
        at com.example.Prototype.ProductsDbHelper.getCurrentSalesRecords(ProductsDbHelper.java:352)
        at com.example.Prototype.confirmFragmentTab$GetEmpTask.doInBackground(confirmFragmentTab.java:109)
        at com.example.Prototype.confirmFragmentTab$GetEmpTask.doInBackground(confirmFragmentTab.java:97)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_layout, container, false);
    activity = getActivity();
db = new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity());
    task = new GetEmpTask(getActivity());
    task.execute((Void) null);

    saleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    saleListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


    return rootView;
}
```

**Remove the onCreate**

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no luck. same error. what i dont understand is when the listview is displayed and the getrecords method called the first time, the listview displays but when the same method is called again when the dialog box closes, it brings the null pointer

Comment: try this in the doInBackground() : db = new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity());

Comment: Hi, the log presented a null pointer error but couldnt identify the source. posted new log

Comment: Okay now here is what you need to do instead of new ProductsDbHelper(getActivity()) place new ProductsDbHelper(activity)

Comment: Hi, replaced it. Now null pointer exception pointing at ... SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: placing new log in post

Comment: What does this line show confirmFragmentTab$GetEmpTask.doInBackground(confirmFragmentTab.java:97) ??